# Using Autofac get error "could not load file or assembly 'system.web.mvc version=5.1.0.0"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac

I'm using Autofac.Mvc 4.0.0.0 and my System.Web.MVC version is 5.2.3.0. It's build success but getting this error when i run project.

Comment: You can load a different version post compilation at run time using Binding Redirect, used by lot of application to change the binary version, check- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks, but it's not my code's problem and i solved it, turn out it's maybe a autofac bug. check the answer below.

Comment: Its not Autofac bug, its Assembly loading policy, which you are not well versed with

Comment: Then why i remove autofac the project run success, you can test it yourself. I don't think have a policy don't let user load from directory with name contain "#". All my project works fine except this one with autofac.

Comment: Asker has [cross-posted this as an issue on the Autofac repo](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Mvc/issues/14). No guarantees the answer determined here will match the answer there - future askers with the same question should look in both places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This problem is solved, just post it to help someone like me.**

Finally, it's a Microsoft's bug already report [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3109075), This issue on github is closed, see [detail](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Mvc/issues/14). Any "could not load assembly" exception may be due to this bug.

**Point is don't let project directory start with `"#"` after drive letter if you are using `AssemblyBinding`**(two project using different version of same assembly, config AssemblyBinding let them using same version when one project reference another)